# Secure internal communications

Tags: security, ssl-certificate

Most of JEE container, storage backend systems... offers a way to use SSL in order to get a secured communication.

In order to get this, I don't quite figure out some issues:

1. Do I need a certificate for each point of connection? Could I use only one and share it?
2. In production environments, do I need these certificates are CA root issanced? What about on testing or development environments?
3. Currently all my connection points (jee container, storage systems) are running on the same machine. So, I think it's not necessary to use an underlaying communication system like IPSec. When my communication points are on different machines, should I need to add some extra security features?

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One uses encryption to achieve three different goals, confidentiality, integrity and non-repudiation.

A server certificate allows the client to verify the identity of the remote server since the server name is encoded in the certificate.
When the server certificate is accepted by the client an encrypted connection is established and the client can identify itself by sending the correct credentials.

- confidentiality - Both the identity of the client and server are verified, neither one can be impersonated. The communications can't be intercepted due to the encryption.
- integrity - due to the  encryption the transmitted data can't be tampered with.
- [non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) - would normally require that the client uses mutual SSL and authenticates with a client SSL certificate, rather than (or in addition to) using username/password credentials with only a server certificate.

> Do I need a certificate for each point of connection?

Almost. Since the certificate is issued for a hostname rather for a specific service on that host you can use the same certificate for multiple services/endpoints running on that host.

Client certificates are typically unique to the client rather than the host the client runs on, i.e. if you deploy an application on a cluster, then frequently all the instances of the application would use the same client certificate. Although you also see that each node in the cluster has its own unique client certificate, which would be shared by all applications running on that node and each instance of that clustered application would identify itself with a different certificate.

> Could I use only one and share it?

With the considerations mentioned above, yes.

> In production environments, do I need to use certificates are issued by a trusted CA?

When you have full control over both (certificate stores on) the client and the server you don't need a CA at all (neither a trusted public one nor an internal one), you can simply copy the public keys around and use those verify the endpoints.

Otherwise using CA issued certificates is better.

> What about on testing or development environments?

The same.

> Currently all my connection points (jee container, storage systems) are running on the same machine.

To be a threat to the confidentiality and integrity of your communications in that scenario an attacker would already have sufficient access to the server to by-pass  such transport security and would directly access the data instead...